# SEGFAULT on using pointer like argument

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

subject of my questino is strange SEGFAULT, throw in this code. It happens in "layer.setTilesetHolder(_tilesetHolder);" part.

```
void TiledMap::loadMap(const std::string &path, const std::string &filename)
{
    std::string rslt = path;

    if (path[path.length()-1] != '/' && path[path.length()-1] != '\\')
    {
        rslt += "/";
    }
    rslt += filename;

    tinyxml2::XMLDocument doc;
    std::cout << rslt;

    doc.LoadFile(rslt.c_str());

    tinyxml2::XMLElement* mapElement = doc.FirstChildElement("map");

    _mapSize = Vector2(atoi(mapElement->Attribute("width")), atoi(mapElement->Attribute("height")));
    _tileSize = Vector2(atoi(mapElement->Attribute("tilewidth")), atoi(mapElement->Attribute("tileheight")));

    tinyxml2::XMLElement* tilesetElement = mapElement->FirstChildElement("tileset");

    if (!tilesetElement)
    {
        printf("[TiledMap::loadMap] Error while parsing file. There is no tileset data.\n");
        return;
    }

    while (tilesetElement)
    {
        Tileset tls;

        tls.setTilesize(Vector2(atoi(tilesetElement->Attribute("tilewidth")), atoi(tilesetElement->Attribute("tileheight"))));

        chdir(path.c_str());

        tls.loadImage(tilesetElement->FirstChildElement("image")->Attribute("source"));

        tls.setFirstGID(atoi(tilesetElement->Attribute("firstgid")));

        _tilesetHolder->addTileset(tls);

        tilesetElement = tilesetElement->NextSiblingElement("tileset");
    }

    tinyxml2::XMLElement* layerElement = mapElement->FirstChildElement("layer");

    if (!layerElement)
    {
        printf("[TiledMap::loadMap] Error while parsing file. There is no tile layer data.\n");
        return;
    }

    while (layerElement)
    {
        TileLayer layer;
        layer.setTilesetHolder(_tilesetHolder);

        layerElement = layerElement->NextSiblingElement("layer");
    }
}
```

There is definition and implementation of "TileLayer".

definition:

```
class TileLayer
{
    public:
        TileLayer();
        ~TileLayer();

        void setEncodedData(const std::string &data);
        void drawLayer(SDL_Surface* screen);
        void setTileSize(const Vector2 &tilesize);
        void setMapSize(const Vector2 &mapsize);

        void setTilesetHolder(TilesetHolder* holder);

    private:
        std::vector<int> _decodedData;
        Vector2 _tileSize;
        Vector2 _mapSize;
        TilesetHolder* _tilesets;
};
```

I'll not show full implementation of this class, i am going to show just constructor and "setTilesetHolder", here they are.

```
TileLayer::TileLayer() :
    _tilesets(0)
{

}

void TileLayer::setTilesetHolder(TilesetHolder *holder)
{
    _tilesets = holder;
}
```

mingw32_GDB debugger said, that crush happens at the end of last while.

Comment: where is _tileSetHolder defined?

Comment: @JohanHjalmarsson It's defined in constructor of "TiledMap". I tried to use 0 insted of _tileSetHolder, same result.

Comment: 0 wouldn't work since the method `setTilesetHolder` expects a pointer. You could try nullptr instead (still wouldn't solve your problem though)